# Google Contact Form Animation?

Tags: html, css, forms, animation, transform

How would I go about implementing the onclick animation seen on this Google login form?

As you click the button box, the placeholder text shrinks and moves to the top left and the button border forms around the text.

https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?dsh=S906398310%3A1668018211534020&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&ifkv=ARgdvAv8SiraKrw6QlE0WDM_jQ_IMyyYjxsvr8JLQ_L2BGzFth9-H3ZsW5aunSdhTVq1iMWqAgCTtg

Comment: You should look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/Momciloo/pen/zoRmxd), doing what you asked.

Comment: I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure CSS I would approach it like that:

```
<style>
    input:focus ~ .floating-label,
    input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label{
        top: -6px;
        left: 0.5rem;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        font-size: 11px;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .inputText {
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 35px;
        outline: 1px!important;
    }

    .floating-label {
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
        left: 1rem;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        top: 50%;
        background: white;
        transition: 0.2s ease all;
    }

</style>

<div style="position:relative; display:inline;">
    <input type="text" class="inputText" required/>
    <span class="floating-label">Your email address</span>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a placeholder. Its just a label sitting absolute above an input field.  There are 2 options.

First one is only html and css. But it only works if all input fields are required. So you cant send the formular if one is empty.

```
    <style>
    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .wrapper .your-label {
      position: absolute;
    }

    #input:focus ~ .your-label,
    #input:valid ~ .your-label {
      background-color: yellow;
      color: blue;
      transform: translateY(-1rem);
      scale: 0.8;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <input id="input" type="text" required />
      <label class="your-label" for="input">Your Text</label>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Second one would be with js and you are able to send also forms that are empty.

```
    <style>
    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .wrapper .your-label {
      position: absolute;
    }

    .your-label.active {
      background-color: yellow;
      color: blue;
      transform: translateY(-1rem);
      scale: 0.8;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <input id="input" type="text" />
      <label class="your-label" for="input">Yourt Text</label>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const form_input = document.querySelectorAll("#input");
    form_input.forEach((e) => {
      e.addEventListener("focus", () => {
        e.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
      });
      e.addEventListener("blur", () => {
        if (e.value === "") {
          e.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("active");
        } else {
          e.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```